# Single statement subshell doesn't seem to inherit ERR trap when using "set -o errtrace"

Tags: bash, subshell, bash-trap

Consider this minimal example, which I run as an executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -E
trap 'echo "ERR trap triggered"' ERR
(
  echo "hello" >/dev/null
  ls /root/
)
```

Notice the two ERR trap messages in the following output:

```
ls: cannot open directory '/root/': Permission denied
ERR trap triggered
ERR trap triggered
```

However, when I make the subshell contain a single statement, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -E
trap 'echo "ERR trap triggered"' ERR
(
  ls /root/
)
```

I only get one ERR trap message:

```
ls: cannot open directory '/root/': Permission denied
ERR trap triggered
```

I was hoping someone could explain to me the reason behind the difference in output.  Thanks!

Comment: It's strange. I would always expect two messages, because `ls` delivers an exit status that is different from zero and therefore also the exit status of the subshell.

Comment: I believe that `bash` optimizes the subshell away when there is only one (non-shell) command in the subshell.

Comment: @chepner I googled your suspicion, and I think believe you're right.  There seems to be certain scenarios where bash 'optimizes-out' creating a subshell.  I've updated my question with this info.

Comment: You've already got yourself an answer,what are you asking now?

Comment: @oguzismail, I've edited my question, and I've added an answer below.

Comment: The *question* isn't a duplicate though, even though the underlying root cause to the question is answered  in that link,and others.

Comment: The guidance on Stack Overflow is actually "if the _answer_ is the same, the questions can be regarded as duplicates". This is obscure enough that I'm still thinking about whether to close as a dupe. The fact that your answer defers to the nominated question is a strong hint that this _should_ in fact be closed as a dupe.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for pointing out that definition of a duplicate.  I was wondering about that.  In that case, I'm on-board with closing this as a duplicate.  But how do you list the duplicate question/answer that is on unix.stackexchange.com?

Comment: We can't link to cross-site duplicates in any official way, just link them informally like you already have. Closing this as a duplicate will not remove anything, as such (though closed questions can get deleted if they receive very little traffic or if they are downvoted to a net negative score, which I don't think will happen to this one).

Comment: For the record, this can be reopened if three regular users with reopen voting privileges request reopening, or if myself or another gold badge owner (or a mod) decides to reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question for closure.

The reason why this is happening is because Bash will *not* create a subshell in certain scenarios, in an attempt to optimize.  One such scenario where Bash will not create a subshell is in the OPs case, where the subshell contains a single simple command.

[Here is a StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466496/why-is-there-no-apparent-clone-or-fork-in-simple-bash-command-and-how-its-done) who's answers give more details about this Bash behaviour.

As for documentation, I'm going to repeat what's in the Stackexchange answer.  The only documentation I can find about this behaviour is in the Bash [source file here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n1652)